# Annual recurring payment setup with Charge add-on?

Tags: members, stripe, charge

I am trying to setup an annual subscription with the Charge add-on, however I am experiencing unexpected results when allowing customers to cancel before it takes the next recurring payment.

What is the best way to set it up using the {exp:charge:form} tag so that the user is charged the plan_amount each year recurring?

Thanks in advance.